# Android Database Connectivity via webservices

Tags: android, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to create android application which will fetch data from sql server 2008 r2 located over network. I am tried following code to do the same:

```
public void GetConnection()
{
    try
    {
    Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    Log.w("Class Loaded", "class loaded");
    String Connection1="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://xxxxxxxx:1433/xxxxxxx;encrypt=fasle;instance=SQLEXPRESS;";
    Log.w("Connection Loaded", "Connection Loaded");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection(Connection1,"sa","xxxxx");
    Log.w("Connection Created", "Connection Created");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

I am able to connect to server but unable to fetch data.

Am i doing this right way? Is any other way to do the same?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: i want to integrate Silver-light web-services and my Android app?but how its possible